# How to remove ?layout=item from urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have URLs that are generated as http://www.domainname.com/about?layout=item
I would like to find out how to remove the `?layout=item` and also `?layout=category`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to remove that with mod_rewrite? I am guessing from your .htaccess tag.

Comment: I don't think mod_rewrite deals with the querystring

Comment: Is `?layout=item` required for proper display of your page? Do you really want to remove `?layout=item` or do you want to mask it so the query string is hidden?

Comment: @Fletcher, yes I would like to remove with mod_rewrite if possible.

@ceejayoz, from the actual URL and that is displayed in the address bar as it creates a 500 error.  If I manually remove the ?layout=item then the page loads,

Thanks

Comment: @Adam Yes I really want to strip, see previous comment

Comment: I'm more confused. Are you serving the about page? Who is adding the layout parameter?

Comment: @Fletcher Basically, using Joomla with core SEF and mod_rewrite on and using standard joomla .htaccess.  this has cleaned all standard urls but for menus it is leaving the ?layout=item or ?layout=category in place.  If I manually enter the URL without the ?layout=item, then the page is displayed, if not then get 500 error.  
Sorry if I am not so clear, but this is a whole new can o worms for me ;) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following assumes that there is either layout=item or layout=category (not both at the same time)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?<=&|^)layout=(item|category)&?(.*)$.
RewriteRule .* $1?%1%3
```

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately it has not made any difference at all.

Comment: Maybe your problem lies elsewhere. Maybe you have to many strange rules for your mod_rewrite. This can lead to 500 errors. Try to use RewriteLog an RewriteLogLevel to find out what mod_rewrite actually does when you feed it with your urls.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, When adding in the rule, it does not remove the ?layout, but also alters the url for all other links.
I have never used the RewriteLog etc, so I will do some research on how to use them.